# Volume Shadow Copy and auditing restores

Tags: windows, vss

Is it possible to determine whether a restore has been carried out on a file or folder from a Volume Shadow Copy snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean can you tell if a file has been replaced by an older version copied from a shadow copy, then the answer is no. I suppose you could compare it's timestamp with versions in all the older shadow copies to see if one matched, but there's no system audit of retrieving a file from a shadow copy.

JR